# Read/write csv from/to different local folders

Tags: python, writer, os.path, csv

I would like to open a file in a local folder, add a comment and then save it in another local folder with a different name.
The code below adds the comment to the file but then overwrites the output on my input df.

```
import csv
import os.path
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4,5], "b": [6,7,8,9,10], "c": [11,12,13,14,15]}) # assume my csv (my_df.csv) looks like this dataframe
folder_input = '/my_folder/input/'
CSV_IN = os.path.join(folder_input, "my_df.csv")

folder_out = '/my_folder/output/'

with open('CSV_IN', 'r+') as f:
    content = f.read()
    f.seek(0, 0)
    f.write('my personal comment' + content)
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter='\t') # here I would like to specify the folder
                                          # where to save the file (foder_out) 
                                          # and also the file name
```

Also, can I save the output file with **extension .tab** instead of csv with tab delimiter?
Thanks

Comment: open('CSV_IN', 'a') use append to append content to file

Comment: I need to write the file csv_in (including the comment I added) inside the 'folder_out'  with a different name.

Answer (score 2):

You need **two** object files, one for the input and one for the output:

```
import csv
import os.path
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4,5], "b": [6,7,8,9,10], "c": [11,12,13,14,15]}) # assume my csv (my_df.csv) looks like this dataframe
folder_input = '/my_folder/input/'
CSV_IN = os.path.join(folder_input, "my_df.csv")

folder_out = '/my_folder/output/'
CSV_OUT = os.path.join(folder_out, "my_df.tab")

with open(CSV_IN, 'r+') as f_in, open(CSV_OUT, 'w') as f_out:
    content = f_in.read()
    f_out.write('my personal comment' + content)
```

If you do not want to keep the original file, then you need to explicitly delete it after you have completed the copy with [`os.remove()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.remove):

```
import os
# After the previous code...
os.remove(CSV_IN)
```

Comment: Thanks for the neat and clean explanation.

Comment: Do you know if I can write out a file with extension .tab instead of a csv with tab delimiter?

Comment: @Elly The extension for the file name is completely arbitrary, can be any length or even removed. Operative systems an many applications frequently (although not always) use file name extensions to determine the content type of the file, but from the point of view of your program the file names and extensions can be anything (as long as they are within the size and set of characters accepted by the system).

Answer (score 1):

The `.csv` can be read and saved as `.tab` in different folder with comments as follows:

```
import csv
import os

folder_input = '/Users/ilayaraja'
folder_out = '/Users/ilayaraja/Desktop/'
file_input = "my_df.csv"
file_out = "my_df.tab"

with open(os.path.join(folder_input, file_input), "r") as inf, \
    open(os.path.join(folder_out, file_out), "w") as outf:
    outf.write("##Comment here##\n")
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the write lines off the with statement. Then start another with statement where you open a new file (with a new name for you don’t overwrite the previous file) in a write mode (‘w’). And then under this second with statement you put the write lines.